# Migrating SVI for vlans from Catalyst to Nexus

Tags: vlan

I'm trying to make sure the transition is smooth the mirrored SVI's are already created but not turned on. Do I simply just turn off the SVI's on the pair of old switches and turn it back on the new switches and right now the traffic of all access switches point to the old pair of Catalyst, I just simply point the traffic to the new pair of Nexus? What other consideration may I have over looked?

Answer (score 0):

The points you need to check are:

- the VLAN is correctly configured on the new switches and on the uplinks that connect them, in both direction
- the routing to / from the new switches is OK (if applicable)
- the firewalling is also ok, especially if you use rules with explicit physical interfaces, since the traffic will not go through the same interfaces

There are various ways to test this. What I usually do is configured another IP address on the SVI on the new switch, then test communication from various point in the network to / from those IP addresses.
On a test host I set the default gateway to be (or a static route toward) the temporary IP address of the new switches as the gateway then test everything.

Answer (score 0):

I would identify existing vlans that are suitable for testing with, if one doesnt exist then create a test vlan, that you can migrate over and practice with. Add a device or two that will experience its default gateway changing and start a continuous ping to devices and default gateway and then make the change. See how many pings drop before reconnection. Maybe the pings wont start responding again, you can then evaluate what has gone wrong without any real consequences.

Once you are happy with the process I would then identify the working hours/importance of kit in the various vlans.

- VLAN 10, this is a server vlan that is 24 hours, we'll do this last when we know the process well.
- VLAN 20, this is an office that is 9-5, we can do this in the evening and if there are issues we can roll back without causing too many issues. Can be done earlier in the change schedule.

There should be a gratuitous ARP sent by the new SVI when you bring it up so you shouldnt have to repoint anything. I recently had to re-ip an SVI and add HSRP to the config in my experience you can expect 5-10 ping drops while the devices learn the new mac address.